# How do I filter lines in a text file that start with a capital letter and end with a positive integer with regex on the command line in linux?

Tags: regex, linux, grep

I am attempting to use Regex with the grep command in the linux terminal in order to filter lines in a text file that start with Capital letter and end with a positive integer. Is there a way to modify my command so that it does this all in one line with one call of grep instead of two? I am using windows subsystem for linux and the microsoft store ubuntu.

**Text File:**

```
C line 1
c line 2
B line 3
d line 4
E line five
```

**The command that I have gotten to work:**

```
grep ^[A-Z] cap*| grep [0-9]$ cap*
```

**The Output**

```
C line 1
B line 3
```

This works but i feel like the regex statement could be combined somehow but

```
grep ^[A-Z][0-9]$
```

does not yield the same result as the command above.

Comment: `grep [0-9]*` does not make sense, it matches any strings. `grep ^[A-Z] cap*` does the same as `grep ^[A-Z] cap*| grep [0-9]*`, you probably meant `grep '^[A-Z].*[0-9]' cap*`

Comment: `grep '^[A-Z].*[0-9]$'` ought to work

Comment: Wow thanks. I edited the question to make my original intent clearer for posterity. The solutions you both proposed work very well for my purposes! Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use

```sh
grep '^[A-Z].*[0-9]$'
grep '^[[:upper:]].*[0-9]$'
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/No3ppT). The regex matches:

- `^` - start of string
- `[A-Z]` / `[[:upper:]]` - an uppercase letter
- `.*` - any zero or more chars (`[^0-9]*` matches zero or more non-digit chars)
- `[0-9]` - a digit.
- `$` - end of string.

Also, if you want to make sure there is no `-` before the number at the end of string, you need to use a negated bracket expression, like

```sh
grep -E '^[[:upper:]](.*[^-0-9])?[1-9][0-9]*$'
```

Here, the POSIX ERE regx (due to `-E` option) matches

- `^[[:upper:]]` - an uppercase letter at the start and then
- `(.*[^-0-9])?` - an optional occurrence of any text and then any char other than a digit and `-`
- `[1-9]` - a non-zero digit
- `[0-9]*` - zero or more digits
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: This will incorrectly match `C line 1 X`.  You need to anchor to the end of the line.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I got more focused on enhancing the original attempt rather than on the requirements. Probably, the regex should end with `[^-0-9][0-9][0-9]*$` or similar.

Comment: I think this needs two tweaks.  First, it won't match a line like "F6" that is just a character and a number with nothing in between.  Second, it matches the number "0" by itself, and the poster wanted positive integers. This worked for me: `grep -E '^[[:upper:]](.*[^-0-9])?[1-9][0-9]*$'`

Answer (score 1):

When you use a pipeline, you want the second `grep` to act on standard input, not on the file you originally grepped from.

```
grep ^[A-Z] cap*| grep [0-9]$
```

However, you need to expand the second regex if you want to exclude negative numbers. Anyway, a better solution altogether might be to switch to Awk:

```
awk '/^[A-Z]/ && /[0-9]$/ && $NF > 0' cap*
```

The output format will be slightly different than from `grep`; if you want to include the name of the matching file, you have to specify that separately:

```
awk '/^[A-Z]/ && /[0-9]$/ && $NF > 0 { print FILENAME ":" $0 }' cap*
```

The regex `^[A-Z][0-9]$` matches exactly two characters, the first of which must be an alphabetic, and the second one has to be a number.  If you want to permit arbitrary text between them, that would be `^[A-Z].*[0-9]$` (and for less arbitrary, use something a bit more specific than `.*`, like `(.*[^-0-9])?` perhaps, where you need `grep -E` for the parentheses and the question mark for optional, or backslashes before each of these for the BRE regex dialect you get out of the box with POSIX `grep`).